# C - Read a single int at the time

Tags: c, input, integer, int, scanf

I have this input:

> Input: 2015

And I want to scanf him like this:

```
scanf("%1d", &arr);
```

But this is definitely wrong. What can I do?
I want to receive the input integer by integer like '2','0','1','5' , and not like "2015".

Comment: Read them chars one by one (and convert each to integer if necessary)?

Comment: Use `%c` to read characters. The integer value is then `c - '0'`

Comment: You mean **digit**. It is like in school. Please use the right terms, otherwise it is unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read each character individually, and convert the individual `char`s to integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t len, i;
    char buff[64];

    fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);

    for(i = 0, len = strlen(buff); i < len; ++i) {
        int curr = buff[i] - '0'; /* subtracting '0' converts the char to an int */
        printf("%d\n", curr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your input is fixed size like `2015` then you can use

```
int arr[4];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    scanf("%1d", arr+i);
}
```

But for general case you can read as string using [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to read the entire line, then parse it specifically.

To read a line on POSIX systems use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), which will allocate the line buffer in heap (don't forget to initialize the pointer containing the line to `NULL` and the variable size to 0, and `free` the line where you are done). If you are unlucky to be on a system without `getline`, declare a large (e.g. 256 bytes at least) buffer and use [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html). BTW, on Linux, for *editable* input from the terminal -a.k.a. a [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)- (not a pipe or a file, so test with [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)) you could even consider using [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html); try it once, it is very handy!

Once the entire line is in memory, you can parse it (provided you defined the syntax of that line, at least in your head; an example is often not enough; you might want to use [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) in your documentation).

You could use [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) to parse that line or parse it manually with some iterative code, etc... Don't forget to check the returned count of scanned items. Perhaps `%n` can be handy (to get a byte count). You could also parse that line manually, or use [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) for parsing `long` numbers, (or perhaps [strtok(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) which I dislike because it is stateful) etc...